# How to solve the Costmap2DROS transform timeout?

Tags: ros, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have been following this [tutorial](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/1.3/user/advanced_tutorials/ros_nav_tutorial.html) and I was able to reproduce it until the last point: Navigating in the map.
I did not modify any of the parameters provided by the tutorial and I am just trying to reproduce the screenshots.

However, when I try to navigate the robot in rviz with the 2D Nav Goal button, the robot does not move, and in the master terminal I keep getting the warning:

> [ WARN] [1467770020.472781433]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1467770020.4727, global_pose stamp: 1467770014.8758, tolerance: 0.3000

One more thing that I noticed is that if I run `rosrun tf tf_monitor` I get that the publisher is unknown, instead of the robot_state_publisher:

> Frame: wide_stereo_r_stereo_camera_optical_frame published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.484559 Max Delay: 0

I suppose that the two problems are related, but I can't figure out a way to solve them.
Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238852/how-to-solve-the-costmap2dros-transform-timeout?/) by [peppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27400/peppe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To solve this problem I had to add this line in morse_2dnav/nav.launch:

```
<param name ="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
```

Moreover, I add to add these lines in the nav_tutorial/default.py

```
clock = Clock()
robot.append(clock)
clock.add_interface('ros',topic='/clock')
```

I guess that the problem had to do with a poor synchronization between MORSE and ROS.
I hope this helps others.

---

Originally posted by [peppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27400/peppe/) with karma: 26 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ltelang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32404/ltelang/) on 2017-10-31**:
where did you gind these "morse_2d/nav.launch" and "nav_tutorial/default.py" files? I try searching for both of them but there is no such file or directory.  I have a turtlebot 3 with ROS kinetic installed trying to follow the same tutorial for setting a 2D nav goal, but I get the same error.

**Comment by [areis](https://answers.ros.org/users/40325/areis/) on 2019-03-04**:
Thanks it really did the trick!

**Comment by [engcarolinasoares](https://answers.ros.org/users/39947/engcarolinasoares/) on 2019-06-13**:
thanks for the answer,
this line works only with the simulation, but not with the real robot.

any other ideia?